# Inconsistent behaviour when using lapply and anova in R

Tags: r, anova

The documentation for function `anova.lm` provides an example in which five different linear models are set up and compared via function `anova`.

```
data(LifeCycleSavings)
fit0 <- lm(sr ~ 1, data = LifeCycleSavings)
fit1 <- update(fit0, . ~ . + pop15)
fit2 <- update(fit1, . ~ . + pop75)
fit3 <- update(fit2, . ~ . + dpi)
fit4 <- update(fit3, . ~ . + ddpi)
anova(fit0, fit1, fit2, fit3, fit4, test = "F")
```

You could also use `lapply` to execute the function `anova` over the models consecutively.

```
fit_L = list(fit0, fit1, fit2, fit3, fit4)
lapply(fit_L, anova)
```

Analogously, the documentation for function `find.mle` of the package [diversitree](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/diversitree/index.html) provides an example in which two models are set up and compared via function `anova`.

```
library(diversitree)
#
pars <- c(0.1, 0.2, 0.03, 0.03, 0.01, 0.01)
phy <- tree.bisse(pars, max.t=60, x0=0)
lik <- make.bisse(phy, phy$tip.state)
fit <- find.mle(lik, pars)
lik.l <- constrain(lik, lambda0 ~ lambda1)
fit.l <- find.mle(lik.l, pars[-2])
anova(fit, equal.lambda=fit.l)
```

Here, however, I cannot use lapply to execute the function `anova` over the two models.

```
fit_L = list(fit, fit.l)
lapply(fit_L, anova)
# Error in anova.fit.mle(X[[i]], ...) : Need to specify more than one model
```

Can anyone think of a way to use `lapply` (or similar functions) to the example from package `diversitree`?

**EDIT 1:**

To clarify my question: The underlying idea of my post is to make `lapply` independent of the precise number of models to be tested. For some analyses, I don't know how many models will be tested *a priori*, so it would be nice to `lapply` the anova across however many models happen to be in list `fit_L`.

Comment: @Hack-R `tree.bisse` is the name of a function of package `diversitree`.

Comment: Isn't the `fit.l` an input for `anova`

Comment: @akrun Yes, `fit.l` is an input for `anova`, and so is `fit`. Both are objects of type *list*. From the documentation of `anova(object, ...)`: `... additional objects of the same type`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lapply` iterates over the lements of a list and applies a function to them. This is not what you want. You want to pass all list elements as arguments to a function, which is what `do.call` does:

```
do.call(anova, c(fit_L, test = "F"))
```

If you look at your examples with `anova.lm`, you see that the output is different if you use `lapply`. From the documentation:

> Specifying a single object gives a sequential analysis of variance
>   table for that fit. [...] If more than one object is specified, the
>   table has a row for the residual degrees of freedom and sum of squares
>   for each model. For all but the first model, the change in degrees of
>   freedom and sum of squares is also given. ...

`lapply` passes single objects to `anova.lm`. This doesn't work for your `mle` fits because the corresponding `anova` method only does model comparison.

Comment: Yes, you are quite right. Function `do.call` is what I needed. Thanks!